# compare generated graph from selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a python script which runs ok, creating a pie graph. Now I want to compare this piechart with another to find the differences. Any idea how can I do that? One thinking is to count the path elements of the graph on canvas. But I not sure how to gather the amount of the them. So far I tried with xpath but it didnt work properly. The line that does that looks like

```
p = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/visualize/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/svg/g/path[5]")
print len(p)
```

Comment: What exactly will you compare? Check size  can be an option

Comment: yea i know. but the size attribute returns the canvas' size. Which size do u mean?

Comment: Please link the page or paste the relevant HTML for what you are trying to do.